# Table border on td didn't show on IE7

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I have table with border for all tr and td 
and inside the td I put

```
<input type="radio" />
```

I give the input display block.

My problem is just on IE7.

The table rendered without border on the td, when I try to remove display block from input the border appear.

So what CSS should I use to handle this issue?

This is the table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="grid rounded small">
<tr class="grid-headers"><th></th><th>Symmetric</th><th>Imparied</th></tr>
<tr class="grid-row">
    <td><span>Biceps</span></td>
    <td class="radio ">
        <input type="radio" id="question-34838" value="21380" name="helpfulness_34838[]" class="styled">
    </td>
    <td class="radio ">
        <input type="radio" id="question-34838_21382" value="21382" name="helpfulness_34838[]" class="styled">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And the style:

```
#content table.grid {
width: 100%;
border: 2px solid #7DB9E8;
float: left;
clear: left;
margin-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#content .grid .grid-row {
    height: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #dddddd 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#dddddd));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#dddddd 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 );
}

#content .grid .grid-row td {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#content .grid .grid-row:hover {
    background: #fff;
}

#content .grid .grid-row:hover td {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

#content .grid .grid-row td:first-child {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#content .grid-headers {
    height: 30px;
    background: #7DB9E8;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#content .grid-headers:hover {
    background: #7DB9E8;
}

#content .grid td.radio {
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#content .grid td.radio:hover {
    background: #fff  url('checks_hover.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content .grid td.radio.selected {
    background: #f9df18 url('checks_clicked.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
}
#content .grid td.radio.selected:hover {
    background: #fceb55 url('checks_hover.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
}

#content .grid td.checkbox {
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#content .grid td.checkbox:hover {
    background: #fff  url('checks_hover.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content .grid td.checkbox.selected {
    background: #f9df18 url('checks_clicked.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
}
#content .grid td.checkbox.selected:hover {
    background: #fceb55 url('checks_hover.png') 50% 0px no-repeat;
}
```

Actually all the HTML generated by JS prototype

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried. Also it would be helpful if you created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that portrayed the problem.

Comment: Seems everything okay even in IE.

Comment: The problem on IE 7 just, even on iPad it works

Comment: If I remove the display block, everything is ok and the border shown, but I need to hide it, is there any other css to use?

Comment: Why don't you add the style snippet that is being applied  to the question?